# Get coordinates of start and end of a view Android

Tags: android, events, view, coordinates, ontouch

Im trying to get the start and end coordY of a view in Android to create a animation.

I tried with the event OnTouch but I just can access to the initial coordY.

I tried to with MotionEvent but it didnt work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();
            //Log.d("S&R", "Y "+y);
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    Log.d("S&R", "ACTION_DOWN");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    Log.d("S&R", "ACTION_UP");
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    Log.d("S&R", "ACTION_MOVE");
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

I only want to know if if the touch was up-to-down or down-to-up.

How could I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: on touch gives u x & y cordinates the change is their values can easly solve this issue. e.g: float yAxis = 0.0f; yAxis = event.getRawY()

Comment: A bit hacky but u can do like: save the first value as when u touch, & when move start compare with the initial value, increase or decrease will indicate up or down

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The problem is that ACTION_MOVE never start, always is ACTION_DOWN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            boolean isReleased = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
            boolean isPressed = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
            boolean isMoved = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE;


            if(isPressed){
                Log.d("S&R","isPressed");
                lastY=event.getY();
                return true;
            }

            else if(isReleased){
                Log.d("S&R","isReleased");
                lastY=event.getY();
                return true;
            }

            else if(isMoved)
            {
               //Log.d("S&R","MOVE");
               Log.d("S&R","lastY=> "+lastY+" currentY=> "+event.getY());

               if(event.getY()<lastY)
               {
                   Log.d("S&R","up");

               }
                else if(event.getY()>lastY)
               {
                   Log.d("S&R","down");

               }
                lastY=event.getY();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Thanks for all guys.